# iterating over json object of arrays of objects, trusting one key's value as HTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the JSON schema below, and I'm trying to iterate over each object's description and trust it as HTML so I can show the link in the application:

```
{
  "notes": {
    "long random ID number 1": [
     {
        "name": "test 1",
        "description": "<a href='http://google.com'>google</a>"
     }
    ],
    "long random ID number 2": [
      //more objects with names and descriptions
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside of notes, there are many arrays of JS objects with the key being a long, random ID.  How can I iterate over each array of objects regardless of the key, and run Angular's `$sce.trustAsHtml()` on the link so it shows in the UI?

Edit:

```
var notesKeys = Object.keys($scope.requirements.notes);

for(var key in notesKeys)
{
    for(var note in $scope.requirements.notes[key])
    {
        $sce.trustAsHtml(note.description);
        $sce.trustAsHtml(note.name);

        console.log(note.description);
        console.log(note.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like that can do the trick :

```
$scope.links = [];
//Get the keys of your hash, object is your complete object
var notesKey = Object.keys(object.notes)
//iterates over keys in notes
for(var i=0; i < notesKey.length; i++){
  // iterates over each object
  var notes = object.notes[notesKey[i]];
  for (var j=0; j < notes.length ; j++){
   //You have your object so do what you like
   $scope.links.push($sce.trustAsHtml(notes[j].description));
  }
}
```

In your html use ng-repeat and ng-bind-html, depending of what you want :

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links" ng-bind-html="link"></div>
```

Comment: Updated OP with the code I'm using given your answer.  It's still not working, also nothing coming in on the console.

Comment: Can you log notesKey and the first for ?

Comment: Logged notesKeys, it gave the right data.  Logged key inside of the first `for` loop, it logged `0` and `1`.  Logged `note` inside of the second loop, nothing logged.

Comment: Ok I'm tired :) I just edit my answer, it's an array so you have to get the value by the index.

Comment: Did this, logged `note` in the second loop, it logged 0,1,2,3,4,5 and then 0,1,2,3,4.  That's the amount of notes in for the two different arrays designated by the random key id.

Comment: with the for syntax in the second loop it will do the trick maybe

Comment: Ok so the looping is correct now.  notes[j] is fine.  However, when adding `$sce.trustAsHtml(notes[j].description);` as well as `<span ng-bind-html="note.description">{{note.description}}</span>` in console Angular returns: Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Comment: Yeah ! try ng-bind-html-unsafe instead

Comment: ng-bind-html was correct, I needed to add ngSanitize.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Ho yeah ! We could use other syntax more readable for the for, like forEach https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach